# {awk} How to read a line and compare a $ with its next/previous line?

Tags: bash, awk

The command below is used to read an input file containing 7682 lines:
I use the --field-separator then converted some fields into what I need, and the grep got rid of the 2 first lines I do not need.

```
awk --field-separator=";" '($1<15) {print int(a=(($1-1)/480)+1) " " ($1-((int(a)-1)*480)) " " (20*log($6)/log(10))}' 218_DW.txt | grep -v "0 480 -inf"
```

I used ($1<15) so that I only print 14 lines, better for testing. The output I get is exactly what I want, but, there is more I need to do on that:

```
1 1 48.2872
1 2 48.3021
1 3 48.1691
1 4 48.1502
1 5 48.1564
1 6 48.1237
1 7 48.1048
1 8 48.015
1 9 48.0646
1 10 47.9472
1 11 47.8469
1 12 47.8212
1 13 47.8616
1 14 47.8047
```

From above, $1 will increment from 1-16, $2 from 1-480, it's always continuous,
so when it gets to 16 480 47.8616 it restarts from 2 1 47.8616 until last line is 16 480 10.2156

So I get 16*480=7680 lines

What I want to do is simple, but, I don't get it :)

I want to compare the current line with the next one. But not all fields, only $3, it's a value in dB that decreases when $2 increases.

In example:

```
The current line is   1 1 48.2872=a
Next line is          1 2 48.3021=b
```

If [ (a - b) > 6 ] then print $1 $2 $3

Of course (a - b) has got to be an absolute value, always > 0.

The beast will be to be able to compare the current line (the $3 only) with it's next and previous line ($3).
Something like this:

```
1 3 48.1691=a
1 4 48.1502=b
1 5 48.1564=c
```

If [ ABS(b - a) > 6 ] OR If [ ABS(b - c) > 6 ] then print $1 $2 $3

But of course first line can only be compared with its next one and the last one with its previous one. Is it possible?

Comment: Personally I think you may find this sort of thing easier to do with Python.  Just `open('filename').readlines()` to get a list (array) of lines, then `enumerate` them to enable checking the one before and after each time.  The `csv` module is useful for parsing arbitrary delimited text files.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am not familiar with Python, I am still learning shell scripts but I guess in time I will start learning it :)

Comment: `--field-separator=";"` -> `-F';'` and you don't need grep if you're using awk.

Comment: Nice I like it I will use this, also why I do not need grep? Since I need to get read of the first two lines to start awk?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "I need to get read of the first two lines..." but instead of `'($1<15) {print stuff}' 218_DW.txt | grep -v "0 480 -inf"` you can just do `'($1<15) {$0=stuff; if (!/0 480 -inf/) print}' 218_DW.txt`. There may be better ways to accomplish that too - I haven't put any thought into what your script is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks,  I see, it works great. However I still didn't figure out how to pass my output to you command to make it work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function abs(x) {
        if (x >= 0)
                return x;
        else
                return -1 * x;
}

function compare(a,b) {
        return abs(a - b) > 6;
}

function update() {
        before_value = current_value;
        current_line = $0;
        current_value = $3;
}

BEGIN {
        line_n = 1;
}

#Edit: added to skip blank lines and differently formatted lines in
#      general. You could add some error message and/or exit function
#      here to detect badly formatted data.
NF != 3 {
    next;
}

line_n == 1 {
        update();
        line_n += 1;
        next;
}

line_n == 2 {
        if (compare(current_value, $3))
                print current_line;
        update();
        line_n += 1;
        next;
}

{
        if (compare(current_value, before_value) && compare(current_value, $3))
                print current_line;
        update();
}

END {
        if (compare(current_value, before_value)) {
                print current_line;
        }
}
```

The funny thing is that I had this code lying around from a old project where I had to do basically the same thing. Adapted it a little for you. I think it solves your problem (how I understood it, at least). If it doesn't, it should point you in the right direction.

Instructions to run the awk script:

Supposing you saved the code with the name "awkscript", the data file is named "datafile" and they are both in the current folder, you should first mark the script as executable with `chmod +x awkscript` and then execute it passing the data file as parameter with `./awkscript datafile` or use it as part of a sequence of pipes as in `cat datafile | ./awkscript`.

Comment: Wow it looks great, I copied your code and will test it tomorrow. It's the end of my shift and am too tired to think properly (after 12h of work)... I will post back the feedback :)

Comment: I edited to insert the commented part in the code as it may prove useful if you have blank lines in your data. Do post the feedback! I'm curious to see if some throwaway code written years ago will help someone. I only had to change the compare function, set it to use $3 as the "value column" and do the edit I just did.

Comment: Hello and thanks, I tried to use your code but I can't figure out how to go from my awk command to yours :)
Also I don't understand this line:

    #!/usr/bin/awk -f

And also the fallowing:

    function compare(a,b) {
            return abs(a - b) > 6;

This is because I don't get how to read a or b from my output. The only thing I'm able to do is to print $1 $2 or $3 from a particular line.
Sorry, still in a heavy learning process. And I don't have internet on my workstations, with a slow network, it makes it hard to google things :)

Comment: The first line (hashbang line) is a directive saying with program should interpret the file when it is executed. Editing the answer to add instructions.

Comment: I tried your instructions but I had no output, and no error message, I assume that my test was OK. I think it has something to do with |a| and |b| because it is not defined. In my example I was giving |a| |b| and |c| as a guideline but they actually don't exist.

Comment: `a` and `b` are function parameters. They are independent of what's going on outside the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70538/discussion-between-raphael-santos-and-raphy75).

Comment: I tried to load the chat but my net is really really really slow... I managed to run your code, and got the exact same output as Ed. I did another test, and changed only one line with $3 set to 0.000001 so it should print it. Your code then printed the line, but also, the previous one as well as the next one. I tried to modify your code to print only the line showing a difference > 6 (the one with $3 0.000001) without success... It's getting closer :)

Comment: According to your requirements, that should happen. Unless that OR in your description was supposed to be an AND (in your question).

Comment: Yes your right, I just realized it now. Sorry for the confusion. It makes sense why it printed 3 lines. Is it possible to do the same but to print only one line. Like it reads the line, compare it to its next and previous one, and print only that particular line if conditions are met (> 6) ?

Comment: Try changing the `||` (or) to `&&` (and). Edited the code.

Comment: Yes it's definitely a AND, I will modify my first post.

Comment: Yes it works! thats's awesome :) thank you so much. Just changed the || to &&. In fact the problem was my problem. I will keep my question unchanged or else it may make a confusion on how the solution was done.

Comment: That's great! Happy to have helped! For next time: try to be more clear, post input data that's more relevant and mark the answer as accepted if it's the solution (whichever it is).

Comment: Yes I will be more careful next time, sorry. I just edited my question because I'm having a problem when there is more than 1 line with a value < 6 compared to the one with a normal value before.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the current line to the previous one is trivial, so I think the problem you're having is that you can't figure out how to compare the current line to the next one. Just keep 2 previous lines instead of 1 and always operate on the line before the one that's actually being read as $0, i.e. the line stored in the array `p1` in this example (`p2` is the line before it and `$0` is the line after it):

```
function abs(val) { return (val > 0 ? val : -val) }
NR==2 {
    if ( abs(p1[3] - $3) > 6 ) {
        print p1[1], p1[2], p1[3]
    }
}
NR>2 {
    if ( ( abs(p1[3] - p2[3]) > 6 ) || ( abs(p1[3] - $3) > 6 ) ) {
        print p1[1], p1[2], p1[3]
    }
}
{ prev2=prev1; prev1=$0; split(prev2,p2); split(prev1,p1) }
END {
    if ( ( abs(p1[3] - p2[3]) > 6 ) ) {
        print p1[1], p1[2], p1[3]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ed I replied to you upstairs cause with the add comment I could not make a proper reply, I think.

Comment: OK I think I start to understand, it's a function to get absolute values and to compare lines. However how do you define p1[1], p1[2] and p1[3] from my output $1 $2 $3?

Comment: Only this part: `function abs(val) { return (val > 0 ? val : -val) }` is a function to get absolute values, the rest is just the body of the awk script. The code that populates `p1[]` etc is `prev1=$0;split(prev1,p1)` which saves the current line (`$0`) in a string named `prev1` and then splits `prev1` the same way $0 is split into $1, etc. and saves the result in the array `p1` so `p1[1]` at that point contains the same value as `$1`.

Comment: Here is what I did. I saved the output from my first post to a file named |code| and I modified two lines to make sure there will be a difference of 6. I then made a little script named |test|, inside is |cat /array/users/geo4/code | /array/users/geo4/test2| and test 2 contains your code. When I run the script |test| the output is 5 lines |1 1 -180| |1 2 48.3021| |1 4 48.1502| |1 5 40.0047| |1 6 48.1237| but I'm only interested to print the first one  |1 1 -180| and the 4th one |1 5 40.0047| because they are the ones showing a difference > 6 with their next or previous line.

Comment: This is why it's important when posting sample input to post TESTABLE sample input/output and not just a bunch of lines that can't be used to test the program. We have nothing to test against and you're now telling us you've updated "2 lines" to make it something that'd produce output but don't say which ones or how they've changed, and posting unformatted data in comments, etc. that I for one have no interest in trying to decipher. I recommend you edit your question so it's more useful/helpful in trying to solve the problem and maybe I or someone else will take another look.

Comment: FYI though - if they are contiguous lines then the difference between `-180` and `48.3021` IS greater than 6 so you SHOULD expected to get the line `1 2 48.3021` printed since it satisfies the test `ABS(b - a) > 6`. Ditto for `1 5 40.0047` being printed as the difference between `40.0047` and `48.1237` is greater than 6 and so satisfies your other criteria `ABS(b - c) > 6`. You'll ALWAYS get pairs of lines printed as a difference of 6 forward is also a difference of 6 backward. If that's not your requirement then update your question to restate your requirement.

Comment: OK got it to work by replacing the || to && as the problem came from me. You are right and I was wrong, my mind was tired. But it's good cause I learned from you guys, I really appreciate it, thanks :) Shall I modify my question or leave it as it is to show how it got fixed?

Comment: Delete the answer you posted, leave the question you asked as-is and accept one of the answers that solves the question you asked.

Comment: OK I will be more careful next time, sorry. I edited my question because I encounter a problem for consecutive lines < 6.

Comment: Your edit makes it a completely different question. Accept one of the answers you got and post a new question.